# Couldn't find Crashlytics GameObject in Unity 5.6

Tags: unity-game-engine, crashlytics, google-fabric

Struggling with adding Crashalytics to our build.

We've downloaded and added the Fabric UnityPackage, upgraded to the latest version, signed in to our Fabric account from within the Unity Interface, and dragged the GameObject from the final step of the 'Prepare Fabric' modal into our first scene. Finally, we've built the game to Android.

After this, playing the game in the editor is prompting "Couldn't find Crashlytics GameObject" warnings, even though FabricInit and CrashlyticsInit are in the scene. The message pops up twice when running the game -- There are two consecutive Unity Scenes that this startup scene leads to.

There doesn't seem to be any specific documentation on the website, and the Fabric website leads us to the download page, as opposed to the dashboard.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. This is happening when building only on Android or Android and iOS? If you're being re-directed to the download page, then our backend believes you don't have an app active yet. If you can share the bundle id or package name, I can look to see what's going on.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Hi Mike, it's currently happening on Android. Haven't had a chance to check on iOS yet. (I've emailed you the bundle id) Thanks!

Comment: @MikeBonnell Looking at the problem in a bit more detail, it seems like the Crashlytics GameObject is simply not persisting across scenes. At least from the editor, it seems that the Awake() method of CrashlyticsInit.cs is not ever called. I suspect the same is true for Android.

Comment: Hmm, this is very strange. I haven't heard of this happening before. I'd try importing Fabrice once more and then save the scene afterwards and let me know if that helps. I'll do some testing to try and repro as well.

Comment: @MikeBonnell I'm seeing this issue as well.  I haven't tried on device yet, but I'm seeing this issue when running the app in the Editor.  I assume Crashlytics will also work in the Editor mode.

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. The goal of this warning was to let you and other developers know that they haven't dragged in the CrashlyticsInit game object within a game, but this is being flagged in other cases due to how we try and detect this.

We're working on a more graceful way to get this point across, but in the meantime, if you comment out line 65 of `Fabric/Editor/CommonBuild/FabricCommonBuild.cs` then this will go away.

Comment: I Dragged the Objects and they are live and active in the scene. But It still displays the warning.

Comment: The name of the Gameobject where CrashlyticsInit the MonoBehaviour is attached has to be CrashlyticsInit

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `[PostProcessScene(0)]` in `Fabric/Editor/CommonBuild/FabricCommonBuild.cs`
Because I only initialize and put the Crashlytics GameObject in my first scene.
I don't need it to check every scene to confirm if there is an object or if it needs to be initialized.

But still not sure if it will have some side effect.